# How do I set optional arguments?

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean

please help, I have this function in my code, that would be a module in the future. I haven't done modules so far, but I would like to allow users to change match boolean to False, but I don't want to force them to fill it in case they want to keep it True
So I would be happy if there is only 1 input necessary but second ( match = False) optional. It's module that returns postal codes or city names based on postal code dictionary.

```
def returnCode(city):
    cityOriginal = city
    city = str(city)
    match = True
    if match:
        city = get_close_matches(city, codes.values())[0]
    if hasNumbers(city) == True and hasNumbers(cityOriginal) == False:
        city = sub('[0123456789]', '1', city)
    return cityDict[city]

returnCode('Berlin')
#returnCode('Berlin', match=False) ... how to?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a default value for a parameter in Python, which can be overridden with an explicit argument when the function is called.

```
def returnCode(city, match=True):
    cityOriginal = city
    city = str(city)
    if match:
        city = get_close_matches(city, codes.values())[0]
    if hasNumbers(city) == True and hasNumbers(cityOriginal) == False:
        city = sub('[0123456789]', '1', city)
    return cityDict[city]

returnCode('Berlin')
returnCode('Berlin', match=False) # these will both run just fine
```

This is actually all you need, you were very close :) if match is not specified, it will default to True, otherwise it can be set by the caller if they so choose.